# sortUsingComparator sorting incorrectly on iPad 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, methods

My company has number of iPad 4s and iPad Air 2s and we are deploying a custom app to these devices. The application runs fine on the iPad Air 2s, but the iPad 4s have a curious bug. The sortUsingComparator method is sorting my array incorrectly.

Sample code:

```
-(void)sortArraysOfStrings:(NSMutableArray*)stringArray andNumbers:(NSMutableArray*)numbersArray onCompletion:(void(^)(NSMutableArray*,NSMutableArray*))callback {

//sort here
[stringArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

[numbersArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSNumber *num1 = (NSNumber*)obj1;
    NSNumber *num2 = (NSNumber*)obj2;
    if (num1 > num2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

//return arrays in completion handler
callback(nameArray, targetArray);
}
```

Any idea what's wrong? I'm at a loss as to what could be causing the iPad 4 to run the method incorrectly. Both device types are running either iOS 10.2.1 or 10.3 and the app was built in Xcode 8.3

Comment: Have you created a breakpoint in the debugger and made sure that `numbersArray` is not nil?

Comment: @SamB yes, numbersArray is populated with the same number of elements as stringArray

Comment: First off, you should not be using `>` to compare NSNumbers. You should use `[num1 compare:num2]`.

Also, does the following work?
`NSMutableArray *arr = [@[@5, @2, @5, @4] mutableCopy];
    NSArray *result = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSNumber *a, NSNumber *b) {
        return [a compare:b];
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);`

Comment: @SamB huh upon closer inspection the ipad4's weren't skipping over the method, they were just sorting/making the comparisons incorrectly, which I still find odd that it only affects the ipad4's and not the ipad air2's. And you were right the compare method fixed my issue. I edited my question to reflect my observation. make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the code above is that you are comparing `NSNumber`'s with the `>` operator. This will not work, because you are comparing the value of the pointers of the `NSNumber`'s! The above code would work if you knew the type and chose to extract it using something like `[nsNumberInstance integerValue]`. Or you can simply chose to use `NSNumber`'s `compare` method.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, do you have any idea why this **seems** specific to older devices? I had no problem comparing NSNumbers with the '>'  operator on an iPad Air 2 and with the simulators. Comparing the value of the pointers **should** give mixed up results, but for some reason this didn't seem to be an issue when I was running my tests on xcode/simulator/iPadAir2.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it is probably just a fluke with data set, or it has something to do with how the memory was allocated. Because if you allocated the lesser numbers first, and the greater numbers later, than you would expect it to be ordered. But, it really depends on how you were testing this method exactly. That could give some additional insight.